# Possible to monitor costs for individual EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to find my way around Cost Explorer. However, I can't seem to find a way to filter by EC2 instances. I tried the Tags filter but actual Tags assigned to an EC2 instance don't show up here it seems.

Any idea how to go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first activate the tags in the Billing and Cost Management console. Go to AWS Cost Explorer > Billing Console > Cost allocation tags. Select the tags you want to activate for bill tracking (I am assuming you have given the EC2 instances you want to track a specific tag beforehand). Please be patient as it can sometimes take until the next day for the tags to show in the AWS Cost Explorer console. For a full explanation read the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html).